# How can we parse a string condition to use in if statement

Tags: php, cakephp, if-statement

Hi I have a string variable (which I'm getting from some other source) as `"$abc=='xyz' AND $yza == 'lmn'"`.. and so on. Is there any way I can put this whole string in IF statement to test the condition. like

```
$condition = "$abc=='xyz' AND $yza == 'lmn'"; 
  if($condition)
   //do something..
  else
   //do something...
```

Thanks.

Comment: what type of input and out put you want to ? have you try something ? can you  please show your code ?

Comment: I'm taking some input from excel file, from excel condition has been defined as Cell A=abc, ConditionCell = AND, Cell B =xyz so on.. All these condition I'm taking into the php as associative array(for now) but list will be too long and static solution won't work as I don't know how many AND, OR can be there in condition. so What I'm trying to achieve is convert this whole row as one string while reading and than putting it as it is to if condition of PHP. I hope it will help u to understand the problem

Comment: @GovindMantri The problem is that you are passing a string into the if condition and thus it is recognizing the string as a truthy value regardless there is a condition present in the string or not

Comment: @Debojyoti Hmm I understand that.. so there is not work around for this ??

Comment: Your question does not contain enough information for anyone to be able to give you a good answer. The Excel details should go in your question, you should explain where the variables stem from, show a real world example with actual data, check existing questions regarding parsing expressions and explain how your situation is different, respectively what the problem is with applying the possible existing solutions. Also, as it stands, your question has nothing to do with CakePHP.

Comment: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327060/dynamic-logical-expression-parsing-evaluation-in-php** | **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762623/how-to-use-expression-trees-in-php**

Answer (score 1):

[eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) will do what you're after, but it's not a very good idea.

```
$condition = "$abc=='xyz' AND $yza == 'lmn'"; 
if(eval($condition))
//do something..
else
//do something...
```

Comment: Thanks... could u please explain why not to go with eval()??

Comment: It is a good idea really cause eval function is the only way you can parse php statements even if the statements appear as strings in the first place.Either use this function or change the format by which you enter the conditions in the if condition in the first place

Comment: @Debojyoti That's not correct. Eval is evil, and pretty much _never_ a good idea! Guaranteeing that there is no way for harmful code to slip in can be pretty complicated. And of course one could build a PHP expression (tree) parser/compiler/evaluator, eval is definitely not the only way.

Comment: @ndm will you then please care to submit a solution to this question

Comment: @Debojyoti No, I wont, at least not at this point, the question is not properly answerable in its current state, and most likely a duplicate.

Comment: @ndm please sir?Give some hints

Comment: @Debojyoti I already did in [**my comments on the question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36759803/how-can-we-parse-a-string-condition-to-use-in-if-statement/36760525?noredirect=1#comment61100610_36759803).

Answer (score 1):

More right syntax with eval() should be (maybe someone else will need it):

```
$condition = "return $abc=='xyz' AND $yza == 'lmn';"; 
if (eval($condition))
    //do something..
else
    //do something...
```

Because inside of `eval()`, condition should end with `;`. And usually it starts with a `return`.